# iOS Touch ID- Should I choose local authentication API or keychain access API?

Tags: ios, touch-id

We have an existing iOS application where username/password based authentication process is in place. Now, We are planning to integrate Biometric/Touch ID authentication. Below is our requirement is short-

1. Use fingerprint authentication instead of existing username/password based login
2. Fallback to existing username/password based login page if user cancels the touch ID pop-up OR if fingerprint scanning fails OR if device doesn't support Touch ID.
3. We also want to store the username & password on device so that we can trigger the auth web service after user finishes biometric authentication.

We are aware that there are two possible ways to implement Touch ID in iOS i.e. **Local authentication (LAContext)** and **keychain services with Touch ID protection (using Access Control List)**.

We first thought that we will implement the Local Authentication method and use the keychain for storing user credentials alone. But since we need to store user credentials on the device, is the keychain access control list is a better approach?

I am little confused which approach to use and which one will best suit for us. Anyone with this knowledge please help me to decide. Please let me know in comments if you need any particular information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you the keychain solution. The credentials in keychain would be protected by TouchID. When someone cracked your application the access to credentials would be still protected by users fingerprint.

I do not recommend you to save password in keychain. Save at least password hash or better save login token.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Do you have any library/framework recommendation for token based login on iOS??

Comment: The login token system depends on the server implementation. Maybe some libraries exists, but I do not know them. I am sorry.

Comment: @KryštofMatěj How will you show Touch ID popup in keychain services with Touch ID protection? I believe you will need to still use Local Authentication API.

Comment: Hi, you do not need use Local Authentication API. if you set right access control to keychain item then the touch id dialog will appear.
Here is sample code: 
[link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html)



return SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(
            kCFAllocatorDefault,
            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
            **SecAccessControlCreateFlags.touchIDCurrentSet,**
            errorRef
        )